# Rails: how to get the corresponding label attribute "for" with radio_button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want make the label text clickable, so that the corresponding radio button is set selected.
For that i need to set a for attribute in the label with the id from radio button.

```
          # in html.erb
          <li>
            <%= radio_button_tag "size_id", size.id %>
            <%= label_tag size.id, size.presentation %>
          </li>
```

the generated output:

```
              <li>
                <input type="radio" name="size_id" id="size_id_8" value="8">
                <label for="8">XL</label>
              </li>
```

The output i want is:

```
               <li>
                <input type="radio" name="size_id" id="size_id_8" value="8">
                <label for="size_id_8">XL</label>
              </li>
```

How can i get the id="size_id_8" from radio button to the label for="size_id_8" ?

Comment: Add lable tag like <%= label_tag "#size_id_{size.id}", size.presentation %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output like this.

```
 <li>
    <%= radio_button_tag "size_id", size.id %>
    <%= label_tag "size_id#{size.id}", size.presentation %>
 </li>
```

This will produce following HTML in your case:-

```
<li>
   <input type="radio" name="size_id" id="size_id_8" value="8">
   <label for="size_id_8">XL</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
<%=label_tag 'size_id_'+size.id, size.presentation%>
```